# How to automatically add &raquo; (») to <li> elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css, list

I want to automatically add the HTML character `&raquo;` (») to the left of each `li` element.

What would be the best practise?

I want the HTML to be:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And it should display:

```
» item 1
» item 2
» item 3
```

Answer (score 240):

I found the above answer didn't work for me, but the following does:

```
li:before{
   content: "\00BB";
}
```

This uses the hexadecimal code for &raquo instead.

A nice hexadecimal converter can be found [here](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/).

Comment: +1: this is the correct answer. But note that IE6 and IE7 do not support the `:before` pseudo-selector; possibly this is why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Nope. `&raquo` didn't seem to render for me, either, oddly enough.

Comment: @StephRose `&raquo;` is an HTML entity, not a CSS entity. You can use it in HTML but not in CSS.

Comment: I've used "\00BB  " (two spaces) to help space the text away from the "bullet point" Might be useful for future reference

Comment: You'll probably want a space after the `»`, use: `\00a0` for a single character space.

Comment: Also had to add list-style-type: none; for the enclosing ul to get rid of the default bullet.

Comment: Another way to add space between `&raquo;` and the text is to set `position:relative` to the `<li>` element, then `position:absolute` to the `li:before` element.  Then adjust using `left:-10px` or whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the arrows to appear as content then why not go for a css background?

```
li { background: url("raquo.gif") no-repeat left center; }
```

Comment: I'd go with `{ list-style-image: url("raquo.gif") }` instead. It's specifically for this purpose and you avoid having to adjust the position of the content.

Comment: There's no reason to use a background image here when all you want is simple text. Using the above: `content: "\00BB" is the optimal way to get the effect the OP was looking for.